# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 'outlet' error occurs whenever I have outlet connected

Tags: ios, swift

I tried every solution on stack overflow for this issue and they don't work. I get this error when I have any outlet in the storyboard connected to the view controller code.

When I disconnect the outlets from the storyboard, the app works perfectly fine. Even if I add a new outlet and connect it, I get this error.[image: storyboard and code]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have set the custom class for the scene in your storyboard. Post the exception message you are receiving.

Comment: check with right click on your viewController in the storyboard that you don´t have any control with the icon of warning

Comment: Do you override `loadView()`?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I don't have any control with warnings

Comment: @Ryan No I don't override it